# retrieve max value ( more columns )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Table with these info

```
patient_id , visit_id , date_visit ( MM/DD/YYYY)
001        , 101      , 12/12/2014
001        , 102      , 12/15/2014
002        , 201      , 12/17/2014
002        , 202      , 12/18/2014
```

i want the result as following

```
patient_id , visit_id , date_visit ( MM/DD/YYYY)
001        , 102      , 12/15/2014
002        , 202      , 12/18/2014
```

the problem is i used max and group by function it's works , but when i tried to added visit_id column it not works

this is my code

```
SELECT V.PATIENT_ID , V.VISIT_ID , MAX ( V.DATE_VISIT)
FROM VISIT V
GROUP BY ( V.PATIENT_ID , V.VISIT_ID )
```

Comment: It is always the maximum `date_visit` per `patient_id` you want. Is it also always the maximum `visit_id` per `patient_id` you want? Then `select patient_id, max(visit_id), max(date_visit) from visit group by patient_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to add visit_id, since each visit is unique by date, so max(V.DATE_VISIT) will always compute only one date.

Why do you want a V.VISIT_ID ? If you want to get the visit_ID at the last date, you have to remove the `MAX (V.DATE_VISIT)` from the `SELECT` and add a HAVING clause like:

```
HAVING V.DATE_VISIT = MAX(V.DATE_VISIT)
```

or

```
HAVING V.DATE_VISIT = SELECT MAX(V.DATE_VISIT) FROM VISIT V2 WHERE V.PATIENT_ID = V2.PATIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try analytics:

```
  with w_data as  (
           select 001 patient_id, 101 visit_id, to_date('12/12/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') date_visit from dual union all
           select 001 patient_id, 102 visit_id, to_date('12/15/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') date_visit from dual union all
           select 002 patient_id, 201 visit_id, to_date('12/17/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') date_visit from dual union all
           select 002 patient_id, 202 visit_id, to_date('12/18/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') date_visit from dual 
           ),
     w_sub as (
        select patient_id, visit_id, date_visit,
                 row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by date_visit desc) rnum
          from w_data
        )
  select patient_id, visit_id, date_visit
    from w_sub
   where rnum = 1
  /
```

Comes back with:

```
  PATIENT_ID   VISIT_ID DATE_VISI
  ---------- ---------- ---------
           1        102 15-DEC-14
           2        202 18-DEC-14
```

The first block `w_data` is just mimicking your data ... you can remove it and start with `with w_sub ...` and then change the later reference of `w_data` to your table name.

`w_sub` ids each "group" (ie partition) by your `patient_id`, then orders it by descending `date_visit` .
The final query rips out just he first row of each group (ie the latest date) .. and all values for that row.

Answer (score 0):

The following query shows you maximum `date_visit` for each `DISTINCT` pair of `(patient_id, visit_id)`.

```
SELECT patient_id, visit_id, max(date_visit)
FROM visit
GROUP BY patient_id, visit_id
```

If you wish to see latest visit and visit date (that aren't corelated) then your query should look like

```
SELECT patient_id, max(visit_id), max(date_visit)
FROM visit
GROUP BY patient_id
```

Remember, though, that with your data being:

```
patient_id , visit_id , date_visit ( MM/DD/YYYY)
001        , 101      , 12/12/2014
001        , 102      , 12/15/2014
```

Query would produce result:
`001 , 102 , 12/15/2014`

Though if your data would look like: (notice change of date_visit)

```
patient_id , visit_id , date_visit ( MM/DD/YYYY)
001        , 101      , 12/15/2014
001        , 102      , 12/12/2014
```

Then the above query would produce the same result - because you just group values by `patient_id` and expect to get `MAX()` from different fields within this partition.

If you wish to get maximum value for every `patient_id` and then see value of column `visit_id` in a row where date_visit is the maximum then you can do it one of the following ways:

1) Using simple JOIN to self-join the table to itself and get the value.

```
SELECT a.patient_id, b.visit_id, a.date_visit
FROM (
  SELECT patient_id, max(date_visit) AS date_visit
  FROM visit
  GROUP BY patient_id
  ) a
JOIN visit b ON
  a.patient_id = b.patient_id
  AND a.date_visit = b.date_visit
```

2) Using Window Functions

```
SELECT patient_id, visit_id, date_visit
FROM (
  SELECT patient_id, visit_id, date_visit, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  patient_id ORDER BY date_visit DESC) AS rownum
  FROM visit
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Above window function simply takes the partition of `patient_id` and within every distinct `patient_id` it orders the resultset by column `date_visit` and then assigns a number of the row within its partition, counting from 1. In the outer select you simply take the row where `date_visit` is `MAX()` for `patient_id` - it's done in `WHERE` clause using alias we assigned in the inner query (here: `WHERE rownum = 1`).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT patient_id, visit_id, date_visit
FROM (
  SELECT patient_id, visit_id, date_visit, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  patient_id ORDER BY date_visit DESC) rownumber
  FROM visit
)t
WHERE rownum = 1